# Adding Many Items to NavigationDrawer ListView Using GetResources

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I have a very interesting bug. I am creating many list items using getResources().getString(). However,
my last listview item displays the second item in the listview. I also tried adding last item as a constant string however, it still displays the last item as second item. Could It be a bug related to that I am adding too many items to listview using getResources? Do you have any idea what's going on here?

```
NavSettingsObject[] navSettingsObjects = new NavSettingsObject[] {
                // First Section
                NavSettingsSection.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.s1)),
                // Second Section
                NavSettingsSection.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.s2)),
                NavSettingsItem.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.i1)),
                NavSettingsItem.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.i2)),
                NavSettingsItem.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.i3)),
                NavSettingsItem.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.i4)),
                NavSettingsItem.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.i5)),
                NavSettingsItem.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.i6)),
                NavSettingsItem.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.,7)),
                NavSettingsItem.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.i8)),
                NavSettingsItem.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.i9)),
                NavSettingsItem.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.i10)),
                // Third Section
                NavSettingsSection.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.s3)),
                NavSettingsItem.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.i11)),
                NavSettingsItem.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.i12)),
                NavSettingsItem.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.i13)),
                NavSettingsItem.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.i14)),
                NavSettingsItem.create(res.getString(
                        R.string.i15))};
     //Fourth Section
    //**********************************************HERE COMES THE BUG**************************
   //Adding one more section item with different string, it displays the second item which is R.string.s2
                NavSettingsItem.create(res.getString(
                            R.string.i16))

        settingsAdapter = new NavSettingsListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.settings_item, navSettingsObjects);
        mDrawerSettingsList.setAdapter(settingsAdapter);
```

UPDATE: NavSettingsListAdapter.java

```
public class NavSettingsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NavSettingsObject> {
private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public NavSettingsListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, NavSettingsObject[] objects ) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null ;
        NavSettingsObject menuItem = this.getItem(position);
        if ( menuItem.getType() == NavSettingsItem.ITEM_TYPE ) {
            view = getItemView(convertView, parent, menuItem );
        }
        else {
            view = getSectionView(convertView, parent, menuItem);
        }
        return view ;
    }

    public View getItemView( View convertView, ViewGroup parentView, NavSettingsObject navDrawerItem ) {

        NavSettingsItem menuItem = (NavSettingsItem) navDrawerItem ;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.settings_item, parentView, false);
            TextView labelView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById( R.id.item_label );
            labelView.setText(menuItem.getLabel());
        }

        return convertView ;
    }

    public View getSectionView(View convertView, ViewGroup parentView,
            NavSettingsObject navDrawerItem) {

        NavSettingsSection menuSection = (NavSettingsSection) navDrawerItem ;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.settings_section, parentView, false);
            TextView labelView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById( R.id.section_label );
            labelView.setText(menuSection.getLabel());
        }

        return convertView ;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return this.getItem(position).getType();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return getItem(position).isEnabled();
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't think so ... it is rather the problem inside `getView` of `NavSettingsListAdapter`

Comment: Okey, I edited my question with NavSettingsListAdapter. Could you have a look at it, please?

Comment: heh ... if (convertView == null) ... else {do not inflate but only set the stuff } ... or put `TextView labelView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById( R.id.section_label );
            labelView.setText(menuSection.getLabel());` outside the if ... in both section and item getView .... also google for `android view holder pattern`

Comment: and also take a look here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70